# vim key mapping for SyntasticCheck plugin is not working

Tags: vim

I am trying to map a key to toggle Syntastic enable and disable on key, rather than active all the time.

I am have following in my **~/.vimrc**

```
let g:syntastic_mode_map = { 'mode': 'passive', 'active_filetypes': [],'passive_filetypes': [] }
nnoremap <C-w><C-q> :SyntasticCheck<CR> :SyntasticToggleMode<CR>
```

However when I press **CTRL+q** or **CTRL+w** nothing happens.

Comment: You mapped 2 keys [CTRL+w]+[CTRL+q] so press them one after another with a short pause (longer pause makes vim think it's a separate key, not a part of mapping).

Comment: oh !! that's not what I want, I would like to have spereate key mapping one for enable/disable check and another for toggle window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split in 2 mappings:

```
nnoremap <C-w> :SyntasticCheck<CR>
nnoremap <C-q> :SyntasticToggleMode<CR>
```